# Class from a different module results in java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-boot-test

I am trying to create a test configuration for my test slice, e.g.:

```
   @EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
            DummyClass1.class,
            DummyClass2.class,
            DummyClass3.class,
            DifferentModuleDummyClass4.class,
    })
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {.....})
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {.....})
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @Configuration
    public class DummyConfig {
    }
```

And then I add it to my test:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = {
            DummyConfig.class
    })
    public class DummyTest {
    ...
```

However I am getting the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type` specifically for the class `DifferentModuleDummyClass4.class` that does not belong to the same module as everything else. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The package containing the type.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Apparently the package isn't part of the `@EntityScan`.

Comment: you mean having 'the.complete.package.name.DifferentModuleDummyClass4.class' instead of  just 'DifferentModuleDummyClass4.class' within @EntityScan ?

Comment: I have no idea what is inside y0ur entityscan, nor if that covers the entity that is missing (apparently not else it wouldn't complain).

Comment: Apologies for my mistake, those classes are inside EntityScan and not EnableJpaRepositories as I first posted it